# Sending alerts / notifications from server side to android application without internet access

Tags: android, ajax, websocket, xmpp, android-notifications

I need to send a push notificiation from a webapp to an android app. 
Basically I just want to inform the android client that new data is available on the server. So it only has to be a string + vibration/sound of the phone.

The (big) problem here is that I am inside a corporate network without access to the internet. This is why I cannot use GCM.

So far I found the following options to accomplish the task without GCM:

- Use XMPP
- WebSockets
- Ajax Polling

Is it possible to include WebSockets or AjaxPolling into a native Android app to trigger events like vibrate?

Is there an easier solution, without that much overhead as with xmpp, since I just need to send a short notification? So far I understand that I need somethink like **SMACK XMPP** for Android + e.g. **Openfire** and **XMPPHP** on the server side for this scenario.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since nobody replied, I want to provide you with an approach I now try to pursue.

I use **Laravel** to write the API. It comes with an out-of-the-box support for Redis, which is awesome to Broadcasts Events -> https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/events

The following is just a quick example:

```
Redis::publish('test', json_encode($data));
```

Those events are received from a **Socket.IO** Server-Instance running on the same machine.

```
var Redis = require('ioredis');
var redis = new Redis();

redis.subscribe('test');

....

server.listen(3000);
```

**Socket.IO** has an android client implementation, which allows me to connect to the socket.io server in a native android app.
Here is an example: http://socket.io/blog/native-socket-io-and-android/

```
private Socket mSocket;
{
    try {
        mSocket = IO.socket("http://localhost:3000");
    } catch (URISyntaxException e) {}
}
```

Comment: How does this work when the app has been backgrounded?  Does it drain the battery?  Is the connection kept alive?  I'm looking for a push notification system that will work on a local intranet (wifi or 3g modem) without access to the internet.

Comment: Im still in more of a conceptual stage and I had the app running for not longer than 2 hours straight. So I can't say much about battery draining. The connection is kept alive if the app is the background. I'm currently testing to put the socket in a service which listens to notifications even if the app is not running at all.

Comment: Can you provide a link that I find more helpful? As I have same situation as you are going through, but I need more detail to understand it clearly.